# Excel conditional formatting based on a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I would like to use Excel's conditinal formatting of a particular column based on values in two other columns.

- I have values in columns A, B, C and D.
- column A has text values (any value user enters)
- column B has a numeric value (any value user enters)
- column C has a text value selected from a set of values (data validation using drop-down):

  - `Start`
  - `Intermediate`
  - `End`
- column D is defined as (x stands for any row number)

  ```
  =IF(Cx="End";"";Bx)
  ```
- user can as well delete the formula in column D thus making it empty

**I want values in column A displayed in red when D is empty and user didn't select `End` in column C.** So this only happens when a user deletes the formula in D.

So I thought of creating a conditional formatting rule that would do the trick for me. But when I try to write the condition formula it doesn't work.

I've tried specifying this formula for conditional formatting rule:

```
=NOT(OR(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("D"&ROW()));INDIRECT("C"&ROW())="End"))
```

but it didn't work.

Are there any limitations which functions can be used in this formula, because when I use something like `OR()` or `AND()` it seems it simply stops working even though they're simple boolean functions that return `TRUE/FALSE`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/113527) I was able to solve my problem.

Here's the solution that actually works. Replace the formula with this one:

```
=NOT(OR(ISNUMBER($D1);$C1="End"))
```

And it will work. Row number will get recalculated for each row, but columns are statically set so they'll refer to correct ones.

### Even simpler

But if we consider that `ISBLANK()` function returns `FALSE` where there's a formula in a cell as well, we can simplify this even further by using this formula only:

```
=ISBLANK($D1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler formula that does what you have asked for:

> =OR($C1="End",$D1="")

To answer your question on limitations: There appear to be a few things wrong with the formula you posted

- The semi-colon should be a comma
- [INDIRECT() is a problem in conditional formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/113527/excel-2007-conditional-formatting-is-not-properly-using-custom-formula-provided), and you don't need to use it anyway.
- It doesn't appear to actually do exactly what you have specified that it should do?!

Comment: My version (and regionale) of Excel uses semicolon and not comma for argumet separation. I guess because commas are used in decimal numbers. Regarding the formatting functionality: I updated my question - which makes your formula to work incorrectly. But thanks for your help anyway.