# Conditional Formatting Based on Prefix Character (')

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel there are prefix characters which appear before the cell contents. Usually this is a blank character and Excel formats based on its best guess. If an apostrophe is used it treats everything as text. These are compatible with Lotus 1-2-3 (',^,",). Since they aren't part of the normal cell contents you cannot search or find for them. Is there any method for conditionally formatting if a prefix character is used?

The previous answer, [Excel conditional formatting based on a formula](https://superuser.com/questions/181914/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-a-formula), has an `ISNUMBER` implementation that works except it will also be `TRUE` when the cell is blank. Since the majority of my cells will be blank to start with (finance spreadsheet) this is annoying as it turns most of the cells red.

This article on [searching for leading apostrophes](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010675_Searching_for_Leading_Apostrophes.html) has some VBA for finding them but is there a simpler way?

Comment: Does using `ISBLANK` together with `ISNUMBER` help?

Comment: Well now I feel foolish. It was because conditional formatting was set as Equal To and not use a formula mode that I couldn't get it to work.  `=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1))),NOT(ISNUMBER(A1)))` worked like a charm!

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Comment: Was already doing so :)

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by using the following formula for conditional formatting:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1))),NOT(ISNUMBER(A1)))
```

*Replace A1 with your relevant cell(s)

Make sure you select the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option under create a new rule to get this to work correctly.